# How can I run DirectX games on Linux?

Tags: linux, wine, directx

I've tried using [this](http://www.dedoimedo.com/games/wine-directx.html) tutorial on getting it working but when it tells me to enter a list of dll's from [here](http://www.wine-reviews.net/wine-reviews/microsoft/directx-90c-march-2008-redistributable-on-linux-with-wine.html) but I only get a missing page. If I could either have that list or another completely different guide, that would be great.

Comment: Keep in mind that wine is SINGLE THREADED.. many games work very well.. many do not.. (the multi-threaded ones).  I can't remember which games but I even had a few that got a higher frame rate than windows.. but the truth is that most games do not play nearly as well.

Answer (score 6):

That is a pretty old guide. To install DirectX, I suggest using a new tool included with `wine` called [`winetricks`](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks). This tool allows a simple way to:

> install some basic components (typically Microsoft DLLs and fonts) and tweak settings required for some applications to run correctly under Wine.

When you  type `winetricks` into a terminal, you will be prompted by a GUI that will allow you to `Select a package to install`. I believe DirectX will be one of those packages.

Before trying to get a game running with `wine` I suggest searching for it in the [Wine Application Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/). For example, the page for [League of Legends 4.x](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19141&iTestingId=86939), details that you need to have `corefonts`, and `vcrun2008` installed with `winetricks`, and that OpenGL can be used if you set it in the config files.

When I have tried to get games running through `wine` in the past, I have found it easiest to run `winefile` (a filemanager for `wine` files) from the terminal, and watch the terminal for errors. Googling around the errors encountered always lead me to a package that I needed to install on my Arch system.

Also, you need to realise that there are some games that simply *won't* run on Linux through `wine`, or if they do, be quite buggy. This is simply a byproduct of trying to run software on a system it wasn't designed for (without emulation).

I hope this helps.

Comment: ` using a new tool ` wintricks has been around for AT LEAST ten years.. there is nothing new about it but this is a VERY GOOD suggestion.  The wintricks script kicks a$$!